# How to use drag and drop functionality for the snippet provided below using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

The following code comprises of the drag and drop functionality.

How to use drag and drop functionality for the snippet provided below using Selenium Web driver. Tried using the drag and drop functionality provided in the selenium hq but not working in my case.

```
<div id="NamingDefaultsContent" style="display: block;">
<div class="rcContainer">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-1 control-label"/>
<div style="width: 100%; color: Gray">Naming Config(Drag and Drop to change the order)</div>
<div class="col-reg-12 col-sm-offset-1">
<table id="columns" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 90%; margin-top: 0px; top: -1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="gridviewlist">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>                                             Position 1                                         </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="column" draggable="true">
<label for="NamePartAtPos1">First Name</label>
<input id="NamePartAtPos1" type="hidden" value="0" name="NamePartAtPos1" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." data-val-number="The field First Name must be a number." data-val="true"/>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<table class="gridviewlist">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>                                             Position 2                                         </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="column" draggable="true">
<label for="NamePartAtPos3">Last Name</label>
<input id="NamePartAtPos3" type="hidden" value="1" name="NamePartAtPos3" data-val-required="The Last Name field is required." data-val-number="The field Last Name must be a number." data-val="true"/>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<table class="gridviewlist">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>                                             Position 3                                         </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="column" draggable="true">
<label for="NamePartAtPos2">Middle Name</label>
<input id="NamePartAtPos2" type="hidden" value="2" name="NamePartAtPos2" data-val-required="The Middle Name field is required." data-val-number="The field Middle Name must be a number." data-val="true"/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you provided here.??  post your code.

Comment: The HTML table markup is wrong - you should correct that first.

Comment: instead of posting html code..can you post URL??

Comment: Its a project going on so i cant post the URL here

Comment: ok..Post your actual HTML code. Code you have posted is not correct.

Comment: Updated the latest code

Comment: which element you want to drag & drop?? and Where??

Comment: I should be able to swap "Last name" to "First name" while drag an drop

Comment: do you edit access for that table??

Comment: Sorry,i didnt get what u r saying.

Comment: The following code i tried but its not working. Error message is also not displaying                                                                               WebElement source =  driver.findElement(By.id("NamePartAtPos3"));
    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("NamePartAtPos1"));
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(source, target).perform();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the drag and drop lies exactly, but this may be useful

```
public ObjectPage filter(int lowerThreshold, int highThreshold) {
    Actions action = new Actions(getWebDriver());
    action.dragAndDropBy(findElement(".className .thumbMin"), lowerThreshold, 0).perform();
    waitFor(elementIsNotDisplayed("#waiting_dialog"));

    action.dragAndDropBy(findElement(".className .thumbMax"), highThreshold, 0).perform();
    waitFor(elementIsNotDisplayed("#waiting_dialog"));
    return this;
}
```

Hope that helps!